# Winsock UDP sendto and get respond back like function?

Tags: udp, winsock2

I am try to figure out if the Winsock UDP way of sending and recieving datagrams has an option to get a respond back to the sendto() like a function.

To make it clear lets say that i have a function that uses UDP to send a message
and needs to return back a true or false state 
Since this function is using UDP to send a message, the application that recieves the message needs to execute a specific command and send back the returned value of true false to the UDP sender, so in that way the function from the control program will know that the function was properly executed or not.

```
Application 1 :
bool Test(){
   functionToRun = "checkandRespond";
   respond = sendto(....);
   if(respond == "true"){
      Brespond = true;
   }else{
      Brespond = false;
   }
   return Brespond;
}

Application 2 :
bool check(){
   return true;
}

DWORD WINAPI IncomingMessages(){
   recvfrom(....)
   //run the function requested e.x.
   bool respondto1App = check();
   sendback the respondto1App boolean to string to Application 1
}
```

Is there any way to get back an instant respond like a function needs between two applications using UDP ?

NOTE : i don`t want to know if the sendto() command has send the message to the other application successfully, i want to get the respond back from the second application like if i was running the check() function from application 1.

Thanks in advance for any help on the issue

Comment: UDP does not maintain any relationship between datagrams sent or received.  UDP treats all datagrams as being completely independent from each other.  If you want to match a "response" with a previous "request" (in parens because only you know that these are requests and responses, UDP has no idea) then you will have to invent a mechanism for doing that. Maybe add a request number into the request datagram and send that number back in the response. Bear in mind that either datagram might get lost, and UDP will neither know nor care that that has happened.

Comment: @Ottomeister Thanks for clearing it out and don`t waste my time searching for something that it can be done. Is there any other way that 2 application can communicate they way i described above ?

Comment: There are many different ways for apps on the same PC to communicate with each other: Pipes, mailslots, RPC, ActiveX/COM, window messages, just to name a few. You really shouldn't be using UDP for inter-process communications, but if you do, simply have app2 `sendto()` its response to the IP/port that app1 is listening to, and then app1 can `recvfrom()` the response after `sendto()` the request to app2. `recvfrom()` in app2 will tell you the IP/port where app1 sent the request from, so you know where to send the response back to.

Comment: thank you for the reply Remy, yes i know how to send and recieve from each application messages using UDP and i coudln`t find if i can have such respond to make things easier.I will try search for your other suggestions on inter-process communications. What is the best choice according to you for inter-process coms for 1 application and 1 service at windows system ?